# Is it possible to check and set wx.html2 to use WebKit on Windows?

Tags: webkit, wxpython, multiplatform, wx.html2

Is it possible to do a combination of a `check` and a `engine-switch` on Windows for `wx.html2` in `wxPython 2.9.4.0` (development version)?

What I want to achieve is; to let the `wx.html2` library use WebKit on Windows if Safari, Chrome or Opera (WebKit/Blink) is installed.

Does anyone have any experience with this and maybe how to achieve it? I also wonder where `wx.html2` looks for the engine on each OS and how it asks to render it.

I tried using `wx.webkit`. But there are so many issues like; lack of documentation and the implementation of the object seems to break on different operating systems.

Comment: The wx phoenix documents give some information on the backends. http://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/html2.WebView.html#html2-webview

Answer (score 2):

How does wxPython know to use Webkit? It doesn't, it's parent library, wxWidgets does a [compile-time check](https://github.com/wxWidgets/wxWidgets/blob/master/src/common/webview.cpp). It assumes Webkit is installed if it's built on Mac or Linux, and assumes IE is installed if it's on Windows.

If you *really* want WebKit/Blink, then perhaps consider [CEFPython](http://code.google.com/p/cefpython/wiki/wxPython), an embedded Chrome. There's an example at that link of a (very simple) wxPython application.